# Run custom build task in x64 process mode from within Visual Studio 2013 build

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, msbuild-task

I have xyz.csproj in which it has custom build task targets. The targets file then points to my custom build task assembly (which is built in AnyCPU). I have some code in that build task assembly that needs to load a x64 assmebly to perform some validations.

When I build the xyz.csproj in Visual Studio 2013 I get a bad image format exception thrown by the custom build task assembly as it tries to load the x64 dll.
I did a log message inside the build task code and it outputs x86 in to visual studio output window.

**How do I force my custom build task code to run in x64?**

I tried to specify the Architecture="x64" attribute on UsingTask node in my targets file, also tried the MSBuildArchitecture="x64" as specified [here in this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264217.aspx). Nothing seems to work.

Any pointers how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Those attributes you mentioned supposed to work. What happens if you build from command line (msbuild.exe) rather from inside Visual Studio?

Comment: running command line works as you might expect. But I need it to work inside VS. My end users/developers are going to be building/compiling the target project inside VS, and they need the validations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the msdn article I referenced, it's actually possible to run the custom build task **within Visual Studio 2013** to run in **x64 explicit mode**. Now the build task code is able to load up the x64 dll and execute validations I needed to run.

Here's how I had to change my custom targets file to:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="SuperCustomTask"
             AssemblyFile="$(PathToCustomTaskDllEnvVariable)\SuperCustomTasks.dll"/>
  <Target Name="SuperCustomTask">
    <TCXBuildTask PlatformName="$(Platform)"
                  ProjectName="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
                  MSBuildRuntime="*"
                  MSBuildArchitecture= "x64"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The fact that I had this targets file open in another text editor (my notepad++) would cause an exception "Configuration file changed in another program" and the build would fail.

Once you close all the editors that have the targets file opened, VS is able to execute it just fine. Lesson learnt.

Thanks for the inputs by @Lex-Li and @Seva Titov

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2013 uses MSBuild 12.0, and by default uses the 32 bit toolchain. Thus, it is only capable of loading 32 bit (or AnyCPU) tasks.

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162058.aspx) you can find the 64 bit toolchain at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64`. If you launch it at command prompt, it can consume your 64 bit (or Any CPU) tasks.

The `Architecture` attribute is used to set bitness dependent tasks. If you do have bitness dependent tasks, make sure you configure both 32 bit and 64 bit, so that no matter which MSBuild toolchain is used (32 bit or 64 bit) your task can be found and executed. It is really a bad idea to provide 64 bit only tasks.

Comment: Agreed, but I do not have control over the 64bit dll, it is provided to me and my build task code has to load it in order to do validations. So basically you are saying there is no way to do this other than running it from command line?